# Publish to Alfresco task programmatically

Tags: alfresco, activiti, alfresco-enterprise

I am using Activiti 1.9.03 and Alfresco 5.2.4 enterprise versions. I have a requirement where I have to maintain the version of the generated report document and also uploaded document (if user edits it). Right now After each user tasks, I am adding two Publish to Alfresco tasks. This is making the workflow diagram unreadable.

I want to know the following things.

1. Is there any other way to handle versioning in Activiti instead of pushing the content to the Alfresco?
2. How can I upload the content programatically using JAVA or Javascript task in a listener, so that I don't have to keep the Publish to Alfresco tasks in the workflow definition. OR
3. Is there any way to hide the Publish to Alfresco tasks on the workflow diagram?

Any help will be appreciated...

Thank you

Comment: You can use test API to upload/download document from Listner.

Answer (score 1):

In APS,There are Services like AlfrescoService,AlfrescoContentService.

You can autowire those services in your Listner and you can use REST Call.